# why my rails app is generating an unwanted property on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I developing an app that allows logged users(Chefs) to add comments to recipes  and  I tested it first in development and works well, but when I deployed it to Heroku the app doesn't work properly, so I ran in my terminal 'heroku run rails console' to check what happen, so I getting the following:

```
@recipes = Recipe.first
=> #<Recipe id: 1, name: "RecipeOne", description: "Potato\r\nSausage", 
created_at: "2017-09-16 00:58:19", updated_at: "2017-09-16 00:58:19", chef_id: 
1>

@comment = @recipe.comments.build(description:'a delicious recipe')
=> #<Comment id: nil, description: "a delicious recipe", chef_id: nil, 
recipe_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

@chef = Chef.last
D, [2017-09-16T16:02:27.645527 #4] DEBUG -- :   Chef Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  
"chefs".* FROM "chefs" ORDER BY "chefs"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Chef id: 2, name: "Wamba", email: "wamba@goths.com", created_at: "2017-
 09-16 01:13:36", updated_at: "2017-09-16 01:13:36", password_digest: 
 "$2a$10$WiIVsMk25EurnDaByNDNH.hWONivodBcvP8.cQJk8cM...", admin: false>

 @comment.chef = @chef
 => #<Chef id: 2, name: "Wamba", email: "wamba@goths.com", created_at: "2017-
 09-16 01:13:36", updated_at: "2017-09-16 01:13:36", password_digest: 
 "$2a$6786544310$WiIVsMk25EurnDaByNDNH67428.hWONiv8900odBcvP8.cQJk8cM...", admin: false>
```

All above works perfectly, but when I typing @comment.save, it fails:

```
@comment.save
D, [2017-09-16T16:04:22.305141 #4] DEBUG -- :    (7.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-09-16T16:04:22.354525 #4] DEBUG -- :    (9.5ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

So, I checked that my @recipe and @chef are valid, @chef is valid, but @recipe is invalid but because @comment is invalid. so I checked @comment

```
 @comment.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000288d770 @base=#<Comment id: nil, 
 description: "a delicious recipe", chef_id: 2, recipe_id: 1, created_at: nil, 
 updated_at: nil>, @messages={:article=>["must exist"]}, @details={:article=>
 [{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

I wonder what is :article and why do I need to validate an attribute that doesn't exist? I checked schema.rb and also ran 'Heroku pg:psql' and I can't find the information about the :article property. I'm sure :article is not in my models.

```
   #schema.rb
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170912043409) do

   create_table "chefs", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string "name"
     t.string "email"
     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
     t.string "password_digest"
     t.boolean "admin", default: false
    end

    create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.text "description"
       t.integer "chef_id"
       t.integer "recipe_id"
       t.datetime "created_at", null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

   create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.string "name"
    end

    create_table "recipe_ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.integer "recipe_id"
       t.integer "ingredient_id"
     end

   create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.string "name"
       t.text "description"
       t.datetime "created_at", null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
       t.integer "chef_id"
    end

   end
```

models:

```
  #comment.rb
 class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 140}
   belongs_to :chef
   belongs_to :recipe
   validates :chef_id, presence: true
   validates :recipe_id, presence: true
   default_scope -> {order(updated_at: :desc)}
  end

 #recipe.rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord   
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum:500}
    belongs_to :chef
    validates :chef_id, presence: true
    default_scope-> { order(updated_at: :desc) }
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    end

 #chef.rb
class Chef < ApplicationRecord
     before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
     validates :name, presence: true,
              length: {maximum: 30}
     VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :email, presence: true ,length:{maximum: 255},
              format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
              uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false}
     has_many :recipes, dependent: :destroy
     has_secure_password
     validates :password, presence: true, length:{minimum: 5}, allow_nil: true
     has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
   end

 #recipe_ingredient.rb
class RecipeIngredient< ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :ingredient
    belongs_to :recipe

   end

#ingredient.rb
class Ingredient <ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 25}
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
   end


rails -v =>  Rails 5.1.3
ruby -v => ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Do you have any idea of what really happens?

Comment: the validation errors are coming from the models, not the schema. Maybe you can show the models.

Comment: ok, I added the models.

Comment: Ok , so can you try to add this validation to comment model? `validates :article, presence: false` or `validates :article_id, presence: false`

Comment: I already fixed the error but with another solution, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the bug is only present in production, I deleted the: article validation in production (which is auto-generated ) for comments with .**class_eval.**

## comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

    validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 140}
    belongs_to :chef
    belongs_to :recipe
    validates :chef_id, presence: true
    validates :recipe_id, presence: true
    default_scope -> {order(updated_at: :desc)}

if Rails.env.production?
Comment.class_eval do
  _validators[:article]
    .find { |v| v.is_a? ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator }
    .attributes
    .delete(:article)
  end
 end
end
```

I think is a rails bug, anyway, Thanks to those who tried to help me.